# PHP with 'enexpected' T_ELSEIF

Tags: if-statement

I am really wondering why this code is wrong, I have already been searching for a solution for over an hour on the internet! this is for a school project.

error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in C:\00usbx\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 344

script from line 344 to 346:

```
 } elseif ($path[2] == 'noteshop') {
 $post = $path[3]; {
 if($_SESSION[login] == 'true') { ?>
```

Comment: As you can see in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) are you sure that you have an if before the elseif ?

Comment: `$post = $path[3]; {` I'm pretty sure that open brace was meant to be a close brace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to terminate the original if with an `else` :

```
 } elseif ($path[2] == 'noteshop') {
 $post = $path[3]; 
else {} // ?
if($_SESSION[login] == 'true') { ?>
```

i don't know your intent but there was an errant `{` which i couldnt understand as a nested expression or just cruft